# Bazel build system: how to reference BUILD file for external http_archive in workspace?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I'm currently trying to update some build files from Bazel 0.19 to Bazel 3.2.0

I have this folder structure

```
Projectfolder/
    |-WORKSPACE
    |-third_party/
        |-openexr.BUILD
```

previously, I had the following defined in my WORKSPACE file:

```
...

new_http_archive(
    name = "openexr",
    build_file = "third_party/openexr.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "openexr-2.2.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/openexr/openexr/archive/v2.2.0.zip"],
)
...
```

new_http_archive and http_archive got merged into one in new bazel, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is now. the following

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "openexr",
    build_file = "@//third_party:openexr.BUILD",
    strip_prefix = "openexr-2.2.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/openexr/openexr/archive/v2.2.0.zip"],
)
```

gives me the following error:

```
Unable to load package for //third_party:openexr.BUILD: BUILD file not found in any of the following directories. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package.
```

other syntax that I tried for build_file are:

```
build_file = "third_party/openexr.BUILD",
build_file = "third_party:openexr.BUILD",
build_file = //third_party/openexr.BUILD",
build_file = //third_party:openexr.BUILD",
```

but all of them give me some errors.

What's the proper syntax compatible with latest (3.2.0) Bazel?

//edit: doing this on Windows

Comment: I found out how to solve it, I'm not posting this though as an answer since I don't understand it. I'm not getting the error if I place an empty BUILD file into my third_party directory

Answer (score 3):

Its to do with how bazel specifies and resolves Labels.

"@//third_party:openexr.BUILD" says look in the directory third_party for a BUILD file then reference the openexr.BUILD file within that directory.

"@//:third_party/openexr.BUILD" would say look in the root for a BUILD file alongside the WORKSPACE file then look for a subdirectory third_party (which doesn't contain a BUILD file) and then the file openexr.BUILD.

So placing a empty BUILD file in the third_party directory is the correct solution for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion sometimes stems from the fact, that bazel refers to targets in terms of packages (not directories). These structures are related, but not identical. Package is a directory in your project with a `BUILD` file in it. While it can be understood in terms of a directory its definition resides in, not every directory is a package. Hence, in a tree:

```
.
├── BUILD
├── WORKSPACE
└── third_party
    └── openexr.BUILD
```

The label of `openexr.BUILD` is `//:third_party/openexr.BUILD`. I.e. `third_party/openexr.BUILD` in root (`//`) package.

If you add a `BUILD` file to `third_party/` directory, it turns it into a (bazel) package and in this tree:

```
.
├── WORKSPACE
└── third_party
    ├── BUILD
    └── openexr.BUILD
```

the same file is now referred to as `//third_party:openexr.BUILD`.